# Why RegionDifference cannot work normally?

Tags: bugs, computational-geometry

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.4**

---

Given that two polygons regions as below:

```
ellipsePoints[mat_, {x_, y_}] := 
  mat.{Sin[#], Cos[#], 1} & /@ Range[x, y, 0.02 Pi]
ellipsePoints[mat_, {{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}}] := 
  mat.{Sin[#], Cos[#], 1} & /@ 
   Join[Range[a, b, 0.02 Pi], Range[c, d, 0.02 Pi]]

mat1 = 
  {{{0., -5., 0}, {-5.2203, 0., 1.7945}}, 
   {{-0.8583, -4.9384, 0.6792}, {-5.4189, 0.7822, 1.8663}}, 
   {{-1.8203, -4.7553, 1.0855}, {-5.6022, 1.5451, 1.9672}}, 
   {{-2.3568, -4.6194, 1.1959}, {-5.6897, 1.9134, 2.047}}, 
   {{-2.9427, -4.455, 1.2502}, {-5.7755, 2.27, 2.1556}}, 
   {{-4.3197, -4.0451, 1.2087}, {-5.9456, 2.9389, 2.4846}}, 
   {{-6.1237, -3.5355, 1.}, {-6.1237, 3.5355, 3.}}};

domain1 = 
  {{{5.0026, 2 Pi}, {0, 1.4113}}, {1.2264, 5.2684},
   {0.6788, 5.5682}, {{0.2931, 2.3402}, {2.9578, 5.7662}}, 
   {{3.2396, 2 Pi}, {0, 2.1486}}, {{3.4794, 2 Pi}, {0, 2.0429}}, 
   {{3.5801, 2 Pi}, {0, 2.0223}}};

pts1 = Flatten[
        MapThread[ellipsePoints, {mat1[[1 ;; 3]], domain1[[1 ;; 3]]}], 1];
pts2 = Flatten[
         MapThread[ellipsePoints, {mat1[[1 ;; 5]], domain1[[1 ;; 5]]}], 1];

Show[ConvexHullMesh[pts2], ConvexHullMesh[pts1]]
```

Obviously, `mesh1` and `mesh2` own **difference of area**.

[image]

```
RegionDifference[ConvexHullMesh[pts2], ConvexHullMesh[pts1]]
```

[image]

However, the above code cannot return the difference of area normally.

An alternative method is using `RegionIntersection[]`,

```
intersec = 
 RegionIntersection[ConvexHullMesh[pts3], ConvexHullMesh[pts2]]
```

then using the bigest area minus `insters`. This time it also failed.

```
RegionDifference[ConvexHullMesh[pts2], intersec]
```

[image]

---

Normal case

```
pts3 = Flatten[MapThread[ellipsePoints, {mat1, domain1}], 1];
RegionDifference[ConvexHullMesh[pts3], ConvexHullMesh[pts1]]
```

[image]

---

Test on version V10.3

[image]

Bug fixed in V10.4

[image]

Comment: I get the correct answer in version **10.4**

Comment: @RunnyKine my version is V10.3

Comment: Well, I guess it was fixed in **10.4** then. (![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/15vtR.png))

Comment: @RunnyKine THX, I have added the `bug` tag.

Comment: @RunnyKine Could you help me this [confusion](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111491/solve-the-boundary-of-a-group-of-ellipse-segments?noredirect=1#comment303768_111491). Thanks:)

Comment: There's a bug in `DelaunayMesh` in  **10.4**. If you use **10.3**, it works fine with e.g. `RegionBoundary@alphaShapes2DC[pts, 1.5]`, but you also get an inner boundary. So just do `First@ConnectedMeshComponents@
  RegionBoundary@alphaShapes[pts, 1.5]`. There's a workaround for **10.4**, first compute the `DelaunayMesh` of the points, `del = DelaunayMesh@pts`, then do `First@ConnectedMeshComponents@
  RegionBoundary@alphaShapes[MeshCoordinates[del], 1.5]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not an answer to "Why doesn't `RegionDifference` work with these regions?" - there the only answer I have is that the computational geometry functions are still a work in progress.

This is a workaround for giving the region you are looking for, by building an `ImplicitRegion` first,

```
{em1, em2} = {ConvexHullMesh[pts2], ConvexHullMesh[pts1]}; 
RegionPlot[
 ImplicitRegion[Xor[{x, y} ∈ em1, {x, y} ∈ em2], {x, y}], 
 PlotRange -> {{-6, 7}, {-5, 9}}]
```

[image]

which you can convert to a `MeshRegion` via

```
DiscretizeGraphics@%
```

[image]

Comment: @ShutaoTANG - it works for me, after your edit (sorry about the mistake)

Comment: However, I cannot run the code that I have edited, which ran for long time and given this [errot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IqGHt.png)

Comment: hmmmm, version 10.3.0 or 10.3.1?  I'm using 10.3.1 and it works for me.  It runs in 10.0 but doesn't capture **both** parts of the region, only the upper part.  But in version 10.2 it gives the same error as you get

Comment: My Mathematica version $10.3.0$, bug...:)

Comment: Yeah, is there any way for you to download the 10.3.1 upgrade? It's just a bugfix so it should be free

Comment: My another personal laptop installed version $10.3.1$, now I am working on the office PC.